# how to prevent children from playing online games by increasingly tightening up the bandwidth

Tags: gaming, qos

Do you know a solution that after sensing game-playing (e.g. traffic on the given port) gradually deteriorates internet connection up to the point of total blockage, and to effectively prevent people from playing online games? Be a script for Linux gateway, or software for the Windows machine where the games are being played?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to just block the game-playing outright? Is the idea to subconsciously make game playing so frustrating that they give up?

Comment: Talk to them. . .

Comment: You could maybe use something like Netsh (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490617.aspx) to cycle the firewall on and off on the windows box for a specific application to degrade performance. Haven't tried it myself but imagine it would make the game pretty laggy. Alternatively maybe try looking into a software lag-switch that you could trigger remotely? Might have the added advantage of getting them banned for using... ;-)

Comment: @nhinkle yes, that's the idea

Comment: @James thanks. netsh seems like a very good idea! going to write a c# application to do this.

Comment: This question is very confused. Why would you want to *gradually* block it instead of blocking it outright? If you would want to block specific ports, you can do that with any kind of firewall software, probably even the built in Windows firewall if you make sure the user playing the game does not have admin rights to change it.

Comment: Also, please try to free your questions from irrelevant details. This has nothing to do with children, and the solution could be interesting for people who are trying to block a corporate network or whatever. Specify your question and make it generally useable.

Comment: Not sure why it's confused - OP quite clearly explains what he's after and then clarifies in the comments. He's looking for something to increasingly frustrate the user to the point where they don't want to play any more. The idea being (I assume) that they are unaware that is what he is actually doing in the background. Whether he should just block / not-block completely that's not really the question posed, whether or not you choose to agree with it.

Comment: many online games require connection only for loading then run also off-line, I don't really see the advantage of stopping internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe use something like [Netsh](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490617.aspx) (Microsoft Windows cmd tool) to cycle the firewall on and off on the windows box for a specific application to degrade performance. Haven't tried it myself but imagine it would make the game pretty laggy. Alternatively try looking into a software lag-switch that you could trigger remotely? Might have the added advantage of getting them banned for using... ;-)

If you want to run it remotely on the machine, potentially combine with sysinternals/Microsoft [psExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897553). I know the older version used to allow remote code execution without any prompts. Not sure whether they've changed that now though.

Answer (score 0):

There are some tools to "test" how applications deal with network failures. Maybe you can abuse one of them. I know about [Vaurien](http://vaurien.readthedocs.org/en/1.8/). Or checkout this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654565/simulating-latency-when-developing-on-a-local-webserver)